# dash app in iframe more secure

Tags: python, iframe, flask, plotly-dash

I'm running a flask app that loads a dash application in an iframe. 
Both applications are running on different ports.

As I'm using flask-user to handle user rights I am trying to avoid this setup. Is there a working alternative around?

I've tried to integrate the dash app into the flask app but this hasn't worked out at all.

The crucial point is to not somehow use the flask-setup integrated in dash because this comes as it is and can't be configured with proper user management like flask-user.

Comment: this is a similar question but the provided solutions don't work for me because of focusing on flask-user - which is user management built into flask.